# Automatically use Default Value for category/product Changes (always inherit "All Store Views" scope)

Tags: magento2, product, category, multistore, store-view

Working on a pretty complex multi-store setup now, and I'm trying to find a way to set all fields as being checked to "Use Default" by default so that a product name change (or etc) wouldn't have to be done at every scope level.

Is there a way to set this up so that everything inherits by default, or a good (and safe) automated way to go through and set this for each field?

Edit: for specificity's sake, let's hone in on one field: "Category Name". How can I set this field to "Use Default Value" on every category, for every store view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer applied to my question as well:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/194328/60595

All store views had the same copy of category name (from a migration), rather than it being inherited from the default view. So I just needed to delete this data.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem and I did this

1. First I find ***eav_entity_type*** for catalog_catagory

SELECT * FROM `eav_entity_type`

[image]

2. I search attribute Id by attribute code url_key

***SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `entity_type_id` = 3 AND `attribute_code` = 'url_key';***

[image]

3. I search catalog_eav_attribute by attribute id 119

**SELECT * FROM `catalog_eav_attribute` WHERE `catalog_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 119;**

[image]

4. Update **catalog_eav_attribute** is_global value 0 to 1

**UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET `is_global` = '1' WHERE `catalog_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 119;**

[image]

Finally output will be like this.

[image]

**Please run all this commands if changes is not showing your admin page.**

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean

**Note :-** *This method will set the value of the url to be the same in all store views forever.*

please click on this link its [enter link description here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Set-all-urlkey-to-check-quot-Use-Default-Value-quot-in-category/m-p/436599/highlight/true#M13356)

Answer (score 0):

> > Set to check Use default Value for Product in magento 2.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` where store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` where store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` where store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` where store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` where store_id = 1;
```

> > Set to check Use default Value for Category in magento 2.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_text` where store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_datetime` where store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_decimal` where store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_int` where store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` where store_id = 1;
```

**Note :** 
In above SQl query store_id 1 is ID of store. kindly you need to check store Id for all store-views in admin and run the above code for each store-views saperately.